# i want to edit my information by id .. but redirect to 404 pages.how can i solve it

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I want to edit information by id :

```html
<td>
    <a href="{{ route('administration.edit',$student->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">
        Edit
    </a>
</td>
```

This is my route:

```php
Route::get('/administration/edit/{$id}','AdministrationController@editstudent')->name('administration.edit');
```

This is my controller method:

```php
public function editstudent($id){
    //      
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @MahfujurRahman, your question is totally vague.  Format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<td>
<a href="{{ route('administration.edit', ['id' => $student->id]) }}">Edit</a>
</td>
```

OR

```
<td><a href="{{ route('administration.edit', $student->id) }}">Edit</a>
</td>
```

Change the route.The `$` is not required in the route.

```
Route::get('/administration/edit/{id}','AdministrationController@editstudent')->name('administration.edit');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<td>
<a href="{{route('administration.edit',['id' => $student->id])}}">
    Edit
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try these

```php
Route::get('administration/edit/{id}',[
'uses' => 'AdministrationController@editstudent',
'as'   => 'editAdmin'
]);

public function editstudent($id){
  dd($id);
}
```

In Blade

```
<a href="{{ route('editAdmin',['id' => 1])">Edit</a>
```

Comment: in this code where is my problem please tell me . Thank you so much for help me <3

Comment: {$id}, dollar symbol not required